# Android Application XAMPP/WAMP

Tags: android, database, phpmyadmin, xampp, wamp

I'm beginner in android development and i notice that when i'm researching and try to create an Android application with Login and Registration with **Database(phpmyadmin)**. Mostly in tutorials i read in different websites, they pre-requirements is I need to install **WAMP** server.

My question is it's better to use **WAMP** server than **XAMPP** server when it comes in creating android application? And which is more advantage between the two server?

Read: I know that **WAMP** is made for windows only and **XAMPP** can run on any OS

I want more clarification between **WAMP** and **XAMPP**. Why did the tutorials in androids refer to use **WAMP** than **XAMPP**. Thanks developers!

Comment: As far as windows and Apache/PHP/MySQL goes they are basically the same thing.

Comment: Are you a windows or linux user

Comment: Windows user Sir Riggs

Comment: WAMPServer makes it easy to switch between multiple versions of Apache/MySQL/PHP/mariaDB where XAMPP comes with just a specific version of each, but there are multiple versions of XAMPP

Comment: And as far as I know XAMPP only supply 32bit versions of Apache/MySQL/PHP on Windows for some odd reason

Comment: I use one of them, but I am trying very hard not to show my preference :)

Comment: Okay sir. Now i understand. Thanks for the answers. It really helps me +1.

Comment: You need to understand about client-server applications. Your server must depend on the project requirement but not on client. XAMPP or WAMP or Apache Tomcat or Firebase or AWS or whatever has nothing do with Android, Web or iOS app using those services.

Comment: And one thing to remember is, at the end, you are not going to run the application in your localhost, you will be deploying it to some proper server. So WAMP or XAMPP for development doesn't make any much difference.

Comment: massive thank you everyone for answering my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually for developing Android application you need not require a WAMP/XAMPP server. The only perquisites is

- Android Studio with Android SDK(Java comes with Studio)

And you are good to Go!

WAMP/XAMPP are used for creating a development environment Apache server, where you can have the MySQL Database, can host PHP APIs, etc.